# Informations about non-Markovianity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, quantum-information, quantum-optics, nanoscience

What are the examples of the practical implementations of studying the non-Markovian dynamics of such open quantum system (e.g. quantum dot)?

Comment: Anything making this question more specific would help. You can Google non Markovian to get an unfiltered list, of things to do with that, that is not the right approach for this forum. If your have an actual question **this** is the place for it, and people will be glad to help.

Comment: thank you for inform me